# JAVA Regex: Making custom regex for String.split()

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to split the string in such a way that only these punctuation characters should be ignored:

(**.**) , (**,**), (**!**) and (**?**)

So if i have this string:

```
String a = "I can't split this string! Guys, can you help me? Thanks in advance."
```

I have this regex (that it's not helping):

```
String.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
```

And the output from it is:

```
I
can
t
split
this
string
Guys
can
you
help
me
Thanks
in
advance
```

If you notice **can't** is split because the apostrophe is given as a punctuation, and I don't want to be.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is a desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String a = "I can't split this string! Guys, can you help me? Thanks in advance.";

    String[] splitted = a.split("[.,!?\\s]+");
    for (String s : splitted)
    {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
```

remove `\\s` if you don't want to split by spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
String.split(" |,|\\?|!|\\.")
OR
String.split("[\\s\\.,!?]+")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've find another different way which also works.

```
String.split("[\\?\\!\\.\\,\\s]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to update two line

```
 String Str1 = "I can't split this string! Guys, can you help me? Thanks in    advance.";
 String[] splite = Str1.split("[.,!?\\s]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid splitting on single quote while splitting on all other punctuation characters OR space:

```
String a = "I can't split this string! Guys, can you help me? Thanks in advance."
String[] toks = a.split( "[\\s\\p{Punct}&&[^']]+" );
```